# Where can I find a gas cap?

Tags: west-of-loathing

In the Deepest Delve Mine, I need a gas cap to make the elevator work. I don't own one, and haven't seen one in the shops that I've noticed. Where can I locate a gas cap to operate the elevator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Deepest Delve has two entrances to level 1. The main entrance is very visible and goes all the way to the bottom. However you need to walk all the way to the right while still outside the mine to find a smaller entrance to the mine. This smaller entrance puts you on the other side of the rubble so you can collect the gas cap from a box in the mine.